# FastCgiExternalServer: redefinition of previously defined class

Tags: php, apache

I know this apache / php error has been asked many times here, and I know that FastCgiExternalServer can be defined only once with the same name.

However I still can't get rid off this problem. My setup is very simple, I have two virtual hosts. I removed the global fastcgi handler I had in \etc\apache2\conf.d\php5-fpm.local.conf.

In \etc\apache2\sites-enabled I have only 2 sites, default.conf and phpmyadmin.conf

Default.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler php5-fcgi
    </FilesMatch>
                Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
                Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
                FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
        </IfModule>
```

phpmyadmin.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler phpmyadmin-fcgi
    </FilesMatch>
         Action phpmyadmin-fcgi /php5-fcgi-phpmyadmin virtual
         Alias /php5-fcgi-phpmyadmin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/phpmyadmin-fcgi
         FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/phpmyadmin-fcgi -socket /var/run/phpmyadmin-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

and I still get this error. To be SURE I have not used the same name in some hidden configuration file, I tried some stupid name in phpmyadmin.conf, like

```
     Alias /php5-fcgi-phpmyadmin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pleasework
     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pleasework -socket /var/run/phpmyadmin-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

and

```
$apache2ctl configtest
Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:
FastCgiExternalServer: redefinition of previously defined class "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/pleasework"
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I really do not know where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

No answer? I got a working solution, so I make some input here for search engines…

```
FastCgiExternalServer
```

Expected first parameter is a kind of uniq key, that will somewhat bind to external server, this doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/q20204/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer

says:

"The filename does not have to exist in the local filesystem."

Solution is use a distinct filename for the first parameter.

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pleasework -socket /var/run/phpmyadmin-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

and

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pleasework-ssl -socket /var/run/phpmyadmin-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

Some url, that helped me to find:

https://serverfault.com/questions/439692/apache-and-multiple-php-fpm-pools
https://git.ispconfig.org/ispconfig/ispconfig3/issues/2188